# Multi-provider OpenID implementation for a Go project

Tags: authentication, go, two-factor-authentication, openid

We need an OpenID supporting common external authentication providers (Google, Facebook, Okta, etc.)

Our project is in Go, so strong preference to have a Go authenticator, but other variants like Node.js may be considered.

Two-factor authentication is mandatory in our project.

For Go I found https://github.com/zitadel/oidc but it seems not to support external auth providers.